# Excel entire column modification

Tags: excel

I would like to modify an excel file.For example I have a column with different prices...one cell with the number 15 other cell with the number 10 etc.So I would like to modify these numbers and add to them the number 8 plus 5% of the new number.For example the first number will become 15+8+(23*5%) while the number 23 is the sum 15+8.Can someone help me a bit how can i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming cell A1 is 15 and cell B1 is 5, place this formula in cell C1, and drag down as necessary:

```
=(A1 + 8) + ((A1 + 8) * 0.05)
```

Comment: Did I mis-read the OP's question? I thought he was asking for `=(A1 + 8) + ((A1 + 8) * 0.05)`

Comment: @Gimp - no, it's just poorly written.  I read `them` in the sentence `add them to the number 8` as being the two cells, 15 and 10.  Although I do have a typo in `B1 is 5`, should read `B1 is 10`.

Comment: No problem, I read the question EXACTLY the same way you did.

Answer (score 2):

LittleBobbyTables answer is perfectly correct. However I have some of my preferences that I would like to share.

I would have a NamedRange for a cell containing the 5% (I would assume this is a sales tax rate so I would name it TaxRate, if it is something else you could just use a different name)

Then my formula would be

```
=(A1 + 8) * (1 + TaxRate)
```

then just fill down

That way if you ever change the TaxRate you only have to change it in one spot. Also using the 1 + TaxRate makes your forumla a little simplier to read.

EDIT: Good catch Gimp, I misread the question. Edit to fix.

Comment: Did I mis-read the OP's question?
I thought he was asking for `=(A1 + 8) * (1 + TaxRate)`

Answer (score 0):

No formula is required. Insert `8` into a spare cell, copy that cell, select all the values to be jacked up and Paste Special with Operation Add. Then repeat with `1.05` and Operation Multiply.